# Create a new DataFrame column from an existing one?

Tags: pandas

I'm using pandas 0.12.0.  I have a DataFrame that looks like:

```
                 date         ms
0 2013-06-03 00:10:00  75.846318
1 2013-06-03 00:20:00  78.408277
2 2013-06-03 00:30:00  75.807990
3 2013-06-03 00:40:00  70.509438
4 2013-06-03 00:50:00  71.537499
```

I want to generate a third column, "tod", which contains just the time portion of the date (i.e. call .time() on each value).  I'm somewhat of a pandas newbie, so I suspect this is trivial but I'm just not seeing how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just [apply](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) the Timestamp `time` method to items in the date column:

```
In [11]: df['date'].apply(lambda x: x.time())
    # equivalently .apply(pd.Timestamp.time)
Out[11]:
0    00:10:00
1    00:20:00
2    00:30:00
3    00:40:00
4    00:50:00
Name: date, dtype: object

In [12]: df['tod'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: x.time())
```

*This gives a column of `datetime.time` objects.*

Comment: Duh.  Thanks.  I knew it had something to do with apply(), but wasn't getting that I needed to wrap .time() up in a lambda.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Using the method Andy created on Index is faster than apply

```
In [93]: df = DataFrame(randn(5,1),columns=['A'])

In [94]: df['date'] = date_range('20130101 9:05',periods=5)

In [95]: df['time'] = Index(df['date']).time

In [96]: df
Out[96]: 
          A                date      time
0  0.053570 2013-01-01 09:05:00  09:05:00
1 -0.382155 2013-01-02 09:05:00  09:05:00
2  0.357984 2013-01-03 09:05:00  09:05:00
3 -0.718300 2013-01-04 09:05:00  09:05:00
4  0.531953 2013-01-05 09:05:00  09:05:00

In [97]: df.dtypes
Out[97]: 
A              float64
date    datetime64[ns]
time            object
dtype: object

In [98]: df['time'][0]
Out[98]: datetime.time(9, 5)
```

Comment: heh. Using Index does seem a little strange here, I wonder if should be a way to access time-specific DatetimeIndex methods directly from a Series.